# How to optimize constants in webpack modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a large module that exports a lot of constants. How do I make it so that in production build, these constants are replaced with their actual values?

I tried both exporting them as `export const CONSTANT_NAME = 1234;` and `export default { CONSTANT_NAME: 1234 }`, both result in the output file containing `some_function(o.a)`, where apparently `o` is the imported module and `a` is the constant name.

Comment: Are you using a plugin that should perform that task?

Comment: You can use [define plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

Comment: @Jorjon I'm using standard setup from CRA, except I replaced UglifyJS with the latest version. I'm actually not sure if it optimizes constants defined in the same module, either - guess I should look into that.

Comment: @laggingreflex but that would mean I have to define my constants in the config, instead of actual code? It makes sense for adding a few defines (similar to environment settings), but it's not a suitable solution for hundreds of constants.

Comment: If you work in webpack 4.x and only one entry, you can use ModuleConcatenationPlugin.